# order of execution Future.microtask with async and without it

Tags: flutter, dart, asynchronous, event-loop, dart-async

Can anyone please explain why the microtask is called differently depending on the presence of an async and without it in Dart?
There is two codes. And when the function with async, the microtask is called first than synchronous code and without async, the order goes the other way around

with `async` screenshot:

[image: with async async]

without `async` screenshot:

[image: without async]

the code:

```
Future<void> main() async {
  await Future(() {
    print('1 future');
    Future.microtask(() => print('1 microtask'));
    Future(() => print('1 inner future'));
  });
  print('1');
  Future(() => print('2 future'));
}
the output: 1 future, 1, 1 microtask, 1 inner future, 2 future
```

And the other code:

```
Future<void> main() async {
  await Future(() async {
    print('1 future');
    Future.microtask(() => print('1 microtask'));
    Future(() => print('1 inner future'));
  });
  print('1');
  Future(() => print('2 future'));
}
the output: 1 future, 1 microtask, 1, 1 inner future, 2 future
```

Comment: there was an interesting article on `dart.dev` and it seems they removed it - found it only on `dart.cn` (china) but do not afraid: only left sidebar is "chinese": https://dart.cn/articles/archive/event-loop (they have a "quiz" section with questions and answers explained: https://dart.cn/articles/archive/event-loop#test-your-understanding)